# Looping through pandas series to return date in minutes

Tags: pandas, series

I have a pandas series that looks like:

```
505     00:12:00
325     00:10:00
2929    00:09:00
261     00:08:00
```

I want to return the dates as an array in the form [12,10, 09, 08]. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
l = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format = '%H:%M:%S').dt.minute.tolist()

[12, 10, 9, 8]
```